# How to completely and permanently unistall sticky keys?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

And when I say completely and permanently I don't just want it disabled, I want it completely unistalled. The service or software that runs it has to be removed. Is this possible to get rid of sticky keys entirely?

I have tried disabling it through ease of access but it doesn't help. Every time I remove the check mark sticky keys is still enabled. When I go back to ease of access the checkmark is still there.

Also tried the registry edits to change the values of the flags, but it doesn't help.

I just don't know what to do.

PS: Tried to tag the question with "sticky-keys" but that tag doesn't exist so I was not allowed to do it because I don't have 300 rep.

Comment: Untested, but have you tried these suggestions? (If you're not comfortable editing the registry proceed at your own risk): http://windowsreport.com/sticky-keys-windows-10/

Comment: Yes I tried those; it didn't work, sticky keys still get activated sometimes. But that article doesn't tell anything about actually removing/uninstalling sticky keys. I'd like to remove it complete from windows. Is that possible?

Comment: You could try disabling sticky keys from Safe Mode and see if disabling it from there causes the setting to stick (ha), but the fact that it turns back on sounds like there's some 3rd party program forcing it on.

Comment: No, Safe Mode didn't work. And seriously, a 3rd party program enable sticky keys? No, this is Microsoft user friendliness at it's core. Good ol' Microsoft. I don't need Sticky keys. I am never ever EVER going to need it. Why can't I permanently uninstall it? And you know what, I got a laptop where Sticky keys are actually able to be disabled, but then guess what: Some Windows updates turn it right back on again. I guess now we now why it's called sticky keys, they are god damn sticky.